# Inject values in an object from another document in Node js/MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest

I am working on an application which is based on React (Front End) and Node js (Back end with **mongodb**). I have been working on the front end mostly while my colleague was handling the back end. The database structure of this application is as follows:
When I add a question in the database, I provide a list of options among which one is the answer. On the back end, The questions are stored in a separate document whereas the answers are stored in separate one; holding the id of the questions as reference. The Questions document looks [image: Something Like This]. On the other hand, the answer document is structured [image: like this]. As you can see, each answer object is holding a reference to its' respective question. If i make an HTTP GET request to get the list of questions, it returns the question object with empty answers array [image: like this]. However, this is not the desired behavior. Back end code snippet is as follows:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const {Question, validate} = require('../models/questions');
const {Answer} = require('../models/answers');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const questions = await Question.find({ isDeleted: false }).sort('dateCreated');
  res.send(questions);
});

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body); 
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  let question = new Question(_.pick(req.body, ['questionText', 'sectionId']));

  //save data in collection
  await question.save();
  
  let ans_Obj= req.body.answer;
  Object.keys(ans_Obj).map( async function(key) {
    let answer = new Answer({
        ans_text: ans_Obj[key].answer,
        questionId: question._id,
        isCorrect: ans_Obj[key].isCorrect
    });

    /// save answers for given question ID
    await answer.save();
  });

  res.send(question);
});

router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body); 
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  const question = await Question.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, 
    { 
      questionText: req.body.questionText,
      sectionId: req.body.sectionId,
      dateModified: new Date()
    }, {
    new: true
  });

  /// need to update ans as well, if admin removes or updates any ans.
  ///left it for future implementation



  if (!question) return res.status(404).send('The question with the given ID was not found.');
  
  res.send(question);
});

router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const question = await Question.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, 
    { 
      isDeleted:true
    },{
      new:true
    });

  if (!question) return res.status(404).send('The question with the given ID was not found..');

  res.send(question);
});

router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const question = await Question.findById(req.params.id);

  if (!question) return res.status(404).send('The question with the given ID was not found.');

  res.send(question);
});

module.exports = router;
```

As you can see, in the `router.GET` portion, only the questions are being fetched because of which it returns empty answer array.
My question is: How can I retrieve answers from the ANSWERS document and inject answers in their respective questions? Any help or suggestion is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Hi Shahrukh, can you produce this scenario in any live tool such as stackblitz?

Comment: I can provide you the link to the github repo as this is only a part of larger application. Here is the link to my repo https://github.com/syed-shahrukh/online-recruitment

Comment: You have to do another query with the question id to the answer schema. and then  add the result to the answer array of your question data.

Comment: @MustafaMamun I appreciate the suggestion and it makes sense but I am facing serious syntax barriers since I am fairly new to node js. Can you be more thorough?